# Keep using a Google Apps Script file after the owners Google account is deleted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

would you tell me how can we access to a Google Apps Script file, when the owner's Google account is deleted?
Actually, once the file owner's Google account is deactivated, the users can't access to file anymore. Still, it requires permission from the owner.
The users in question have already access to the file whithin the shared Drive.

Comment: Copy the file and load into script editor as a gs file.  Save it and run it.  Other modification may be required like folder id's and things unique to the original authers system.  Share the code if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. Right. This means that each time we’ll be having a new project manager, we’ll need to copy & paste the file.

Comment: It can also be managed with the Apps Script API but that will require some learning on your part.

Answer (score 1):

Files in a Shared Drive are owned by the domain, not by individual accounts. As these files aren't owned by individual accounts, they will not be deleted when an user account is deleted.

If users have problems to access files in the Shared Drive, review the Shared Drive settings. You might need to get help from the Google Workspace admin.

Reference

- [What are shared drives?](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7212025?hl=en)